# C# sorting a list of (sub)directories with natural sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, natural-sort

I'm trying to sort a list of directories and subdirectories with natural sorting and right now it isn't entirely what I want.

Right now I'm getting this:

```
    D:/pictures/apples/a.txt
    D:/pictures/apples pink/c.txt
    D:/pictures/bananas/asdasd.txt
    D:/pictures/lemons/foo.txt
    D:/pictures/lemons yellow/bar.txt
    D:/pictures/lemons/fresh/c.txt
    D:/pictures/oranges/341/d.txt
```

What I want is this:

```
    D:/pictures/apples/a.txt
    D:/pictures/apples pink/c.txt
    D:/pictures/bananas/asdasd.txt
    D:/pictures/lemons/foo.txt
    D:/pictures/lemons/fresh/c.txt
    D:/pictures/lemons yellow/bar.txt
    D:/pictures/oranges/341/d.txt
```

Note the subdirectory of lemons should be before the other.

For natural sorting, I'm using the built-in function of Windows as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp) and I'm using the following code to achieve the above:

```
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .OrderBy(f => Path.GetDirectoryName(f), new NaturalSortComparer())
        .ThenBy(f => f.Count(c => c == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar || c == Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar))
        .Where(file => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file.ToLower())));
```